# $Y$ closed in $X$ and $A\subseteq Y \subseteq X $ $ \implies$ $cl(A)$ in $X$ equals $cl(A)$ in $Y$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\subseteq Y \subseteq X$. And suppose $Y$ is closed in $X$.

How would you prove $cl (A)$ in $X$ is equal to $cl(A)$ in $Y$ ?

I was thinking about using the definition $cl(A)= \bigcap F$ ,  $F$ closed of $ X$, $F \subseteq A$ for $X$ and for $Y$ and then making a correspondence between an $F$ from the $cl(A)$ in $X$ and an $F'$ from the $cl(A)$ in $Y$ by using the theorem: "$F$ closed in $Y$, if and only if, $\exists F'$ closed in $X$ , $F=F'\cap Y$".

Comment: Is it true? $(0,1) \subset (0,1] \subset [0,1]$ but  $cl((0,1))$ in $(0,1]$ is $(0,1]$ and $cl((0,1))$ in $[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: Think about the case $A=Y=(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}=X$. What can you say about $\mathrm{cl}_Y(A)$? And $\mathrm{cl}_X(A)$? Is there an inclusion you can still show using your idea?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think we can still show the inclusion $\mathrm {cl} _Y (A) \subseteq \mathrm {cl} _X (A)$. What I had in mind actually was the example of $(1,2)$ which is a subset of $\mathbb R =Y$. Here in this case, if $X$ is $\mathbb R^2$ I think my "result" is true. Your counterexamples are cases where one endpoint of $A$ coincides with one endpoint of $X$ I think.

Comment: Their counter-example still works if $X=\mathbb{R}$ instead of $[0,1]$. For the equality to be true, you need $Y$ to be closed in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your edit that assumes $Y$ is closed in $X$, here's a proof.

As you suggest, $cl_Y(A)=\bigcap\mathcal H$ where $\mathcal H$ is all closed-in-$Y$ sets containing $A$, and $cl(A)=\bigcap\mathcal L$ where $\mathcal L$ is all closed-in-$X$ sets containing $A$.

Note that $\bigcap\mathcal H=\bigcap\{L\cap Y:L\in\mathcal L\}\subseteq\bigcap\mathcal L$. So $cl_Y(A)\subseteq cl(A)$.

On the other hand, if $x\in \bigcap\mathcal L$, we know $x\in L$ for all $L\in\mathcal L$. In particular, $x\in Y$ since $Y\in\mathcal L$. Thus $x\in L\cap Y$ for all $L\in\mathcal L$. This shows $\bigcap\mathcal L\subseteq\bigcap\{L\cap Y:L\in\mathcal L\}=\bigcap H$. Therefore $cl(A)\subseteq cl_Y(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark**: If we denote the topology on $X$ by $\mathcal T_X,$ then the subspace topology on $Y$ inherited from $\mathcal T_X$ is $\mathcal T_Y=\{Y\cap U:U\in\mathcal T_X\}.$ As an immediate consequence, each subset of $Y$ that is *closed* relative to $\mathcal T_Y$ has form $Y\setminus (Y\cap U)=Y\cap(X\setminus U)$ for some $U\in\mathcal T.$ Put another way, every $\mathcal T_Y$-closed subset of $Y$ is of the form $Y\cap F$ for some $\mathcal T_X$-closed subset $F$ of $X.$

---

There's another way to think about closure that makes the result more intuitive, and makes it clearer why we need the hypothesis that $Y$ is $\mathcal T_X$-closed.

Given a set $Z$ with a topology $\mathcal T$ and a subset $S$ of $Z,$ $\operatorname{cl}(S,\mathcal T)$ is the smallest subset of $Z$ containing $S$ which is $\mathcal T$-closed. Put more rigorously, the $\operatorname{cl}(S,\mathcal T)$ is a set $C$ with the following properties:

- $S\subseteq C\subseteq Z,$
- $Z\setminus C\in\mathcal T,$ and
- if $S\subseteq K\subseteq Z$ is such that $Z\setminus K\in\mathcal T,$ then $C\subseteq K.$

It is easy to prove that these conditions determine a unique $\mathcal T$-closed superset of $S$ regardless of what the set $Z$ is, regardless of which topology $\mathcal T$ on $Z$ we're talking about, and regardless of which subset $S$ of $Z$ we're talking about. Moreover, it follows very easily that the closure of $S$ in a topological space $\langle Z,\mathcal T\rangle$ (in the sense of the intersection of closed supersets) is the set $\operatorname{cl}(S,\mathcal T).$

Now, let's see how this alternative definition simplifies things here, by letting $\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X)$ and $\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_Y)$ (respectively) indicate the smallest $\mathcal T_X$-closed superset of $A$ and the smallest $\mathcal T_Y$-closed superset of $A.$

Even if we *don't* assume that $Y$ is $\mathcal T_X$-closed, we can readily conclude that $\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_Y)=Y\cap\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X).$ Indeed, it is trivial to verify that $Y\cap\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X)$ is a subset of $Y,$ a superset of $A,$ and $\mathcal T_Y$-closed. Moreover, letting $K$ be any subset of $Y$ that is a $\mathcal T_Y$-closed superset of $A,$ we have by the Remark that $K=Y\cap F$ for some $F\subseteq X$ such that $X\setminus F\in\mathcal T_X.$ Since $A\subseteq K=Y\cap F\subseteq F\subseteq X,$ then by the definition of $\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X),$ we have $\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X)\subseteq F,$ so that $Y\cap\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X)\subseteq Y\cap F=K.$ Having satisfied all conditions of the definition, $Y\cap\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X)=\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_Y).$

Finally, the hypothesis that $Y$ is $\mathcal T_X$-closed comes in handy, because in that case, $\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_Y)$ is itself a $\mathcal T_X$-closed superset of $A$ and a subset of $X.$ By definition of $\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X),$ then, we must have $$\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_Y)=Y\cap\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A,\mathcal T_X).$$ By double inclusion, we have the desired equality. This also shows exactly why we need the hypothesis that $Y$ is $\mathcal T_X$-closed.